# Convert function with generic type swift 2 to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have started learning Swift 3 for several weeks and I have a project that I have to convert from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

I've read many documents but I don't know how to convert this function (I don't know exactly the keyword to search).

```
func pickImageFromCamera<T: UIViewController(_ delegate: T) where T: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = delegate;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        delegate.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It gives the following error message:

```
expected '>' to complete generic argument list
```

Update:
This is the original code:

```
func pickImageFromCamera<T: UIViewController where T: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>>(delegate: T){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = delegate;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        delegate.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit your question with your attempted Swift 3 code and clearly indicate the part you are having trouble with.

Comment: `protocol<>` notation is no longer used.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question. I think that the code was partially converted but not yet fully.

Comment: @matt: so how to reuse this function? :(

Comment: I don't see how this can be valid Swift 2 code

Comment: hi all, thank for your all comments. I checked the project again and found that this function was auto converted. I've updated the original code above. Can you help me to convert it to Swift 3. I can't rewrite this function because it used too much in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this my self, when I first came across it.

```
 func pickImageFromCamera(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self
        myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera` with just `.camera`.

Comment: You missed one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all, i found the solution. Because the auto-converting makes this function become so confused.

```
func pickImageFromCamera<T: UIViewController>(delegate: T) where T: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = delegate;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        delegate.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```